# How to adda new module to MongooseIm chat server written over ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I am trying to add the mod_zeropush module to the existing ejabberd MongooseIm server.

I copied the beam file to location where all beam files are there in the `rel` folder.

When do the `$sudo bin/mongooseimctl debug` command and finding the mod_ all entries matching with mod_... I see all except my `mod_zeropush`.

Can anyone help me how they made this module add to their chat server.

Raised this issue to Github guys as well : [MongooseIM GitHub](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/1048)

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by getting some help and would like share how its added to `MongooseIM`.

This setup is done on a server running `Ubuntu 16.04`.

1. After you downloaded `mod_zeropush.erl` (maybe from [here](https://github.com/aadimurthy/mod_zeropush-Mongooseim-/blob/master/mod_zeropush.erl)), put it in the location as mentioned below:

   ```
   `<GitSourceMongooseFolder>/apps/ejabberd/src/mod_zeropush.erl`
   ```
2. Run `sudo make` in `MongooseIM` directory.
3. After the build is done, the beam file is created in the `rel`
   folder at location given below:

   `/MongooseIM/rel/mongooseim/lib/ejabberd-2.1.8+mim-2.0.0beta2-312-g3cec442/ebin`
4. Add the following code to `ejabberd.cfg` in `modules` section.

   ```
    {mod_zeropush, [
       {sound, "default"},
       {auth_token, "myapp-chat-token"},
       {post_url, "http://my.url/mypath"}
     ]},
   ```
5. Go to `rel/mongooseim` folder and enter the command `sudo
   bin/mongooseimctl debug`
6. Check by entering `mod_` on shell prompt then `Tab`; you should see
   `mod_zero`
7. Go to `root/rel` github directory and `sudo bin/mongooseim restart`

Done. You should receive offline messages on your web server.